# how to edit stream of data in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

My data in MSword looks like this,"C0 00 00 FE 08 FF FB FF"
I want to add 0x and it should be comma separated ,so the final format will look like "0xC0,0x00,0x00,0xFE,0x08,0xFF".How can i make it in the required format in  Microsoft Word?Currently I am doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with it is using ***Find and Replace*** and manually replace only the first one.

**Steps:**

**1.** Select the text as shown below:

[image]

**2.** Press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+ <kbd>**H**</kbd> to open this window:

[image: Ctrl+H window]

**3.** Enter <kbd>**Space**</kbd> character in *"Find what"* and <kbd>**,**</kbd><kbd>**0**</kbd><kbd>**x**</kbd> in *"Replace with"*.

**4.** Click on "Replace All" to get this:

[image]

 Click "Yes" or "No" according to your preference. For this case, I clicked No.

**5.** Manually adjust the first one to `0xC0`.

---

In this way, you would have to adjust the first one manually and the rest will be taken care of by *Find and Replace*.